# status page with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make a status page on my app. This page should show the status of Resque and Faye
Is there a way to get the status of these services inside my Rails App? I tried with http request/responses like [this](http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html) but all i got was timeouts.

the code that originated a timeout

```
def index
    url = URI.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8080/faye.js')
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
    res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
      http.request(req)
    }

    @status_push = res.body
```

Comment: I use the Resque Status plugin for Resque (https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status), and as for Faye, have you tried localhost vs 127.0.0.1?

Comment: tried with localhost. no success too. i will take a look @resque-status, but at a first glance, seem like a plugin to get the status of my jobs, not the resque itself

Comment: Ok, you just want to see if those are up and running. Resque Status is for job status, so that probably won't do what you want--sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done with [god](http://godrb.com/). i can `'god status {service}'` and handle the output. thank you all

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to monitor the queues and their sizes, then monitoring resque is way too easy. Just use the [Resque class and call its methods](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/blob/master/lib/resque.rb).